# Why am I getting a flat likelihood function from an exponential distribution?

Tags: r, likelihood, exponential-distribution

I have 10 values that come from an exponential distribution. And I'm trying to draw the likelihood function by fixing these values and changing the unknown alpha.

I calculated the function and did a rescale of the function so that it would integrate to 1.

But the result is a really flat function with only one peak. And when I compare it to a Gamma (1,1) distribution the whole rescaled likelihood function is just a flat line. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code in R if that helps:

```
y <- c(52586, 20246,  6336, 46680, 10918, 26286, 20540, 3398, 30122, 58020)
# Rescale 
k <- integrate(function(th)dexp(y, rate = th), lower=0, upper=1)$value
plot(function(th)dexp(y, rate = th)/k)

# Comparison
a <- 1
b <- 1
plot(function(x)dgamma(x, a, b), ylab="", xlab = expression(lambda))
plot(function(th)dexp(y, rate = th)/k, lty = 2, col = 'blue', add = T)
```

I'm guessing this is happening because I don't have enough data and it's very sparse? Or am I supposed to sum the variables and convert it to a gamma(n, lambda)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood is 
$$
f(y_1,\ldots,y_n;\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(y_i;\lambda) = \lambda^n \exp\left[-\lambda \sum_i y_i\right].
$$
The log-likelihood is 
$$
l = n\log\lambda - \lambda \sum_i y_i.
$$

The maximum likelihood estimate is $\hat{\lambda} = 1/\bar{Y} = 3.634619e-05$, so you might want to plot the functions around that value. Also, $\lambda > 0$, so don't plot that value.

Here's some R code you can play around with

```
y <- c(52586, 20246,  6336, 46680, 10918, 26286, 20540, 3398, 30122, 58020)
n <- length(y)

like <- function(lambda){
  lambda^n * exp(-lambda*sum(y))
}

loglike <- function(lambda){
  n*log(lambda) - lambda * sum(y)
}

someLambdas <- seq(0.000000001,.001,.0001)
plot(someLambdas, sapply(someLambdas, like), main = "likelihood", type = "l")
plot(someLambdas, sapply(someLambdas, loglike), main = "log-likelihood", type = "l")
```

Comment: Given this is probably homework, guidance and hints rather than explicit solutions would normally be called for (e.g.see the section on homework in the [help/on-topic]). You may have just done the OP's assignment there, including stuff he hadn't even thought to ask yet.

Comment: Thanks! I already had done something similar before but i didn't think of doing it in function form! That way i used the function integrate to find the rescale value. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

[Much too long for comments and this contains at least a partial answer...]

1. There's no reason to scale a likelihood to integrate to 1. It's not a density.
2. Rather that require people to understand your code to figure out what you're trying to achieve, *first* explain what you're trying to implement in code, in detail. That is, *show your algebra*, then we can tell you if you're even trying to implement the right thing. If it's not the right quantity it's a waste of time to read all your code. On the other hand if you are trying to implement the right thing, it's a coding problem (and probably goes elsewhere).
3. As it turns out, you're not calculating the right thing but it's not clear whether you don't understand likelihood or you don't understand what R is doing (writing it down would clarify). Since `y` is a vector, calling `dexp` on it returns a vector at a given value for the parameter. You need a number for the likelihood at a specific parameter value. Can you see what you should have done instead?
4. The function you do plot isn't flat, it's got a huge peak in it. Your choice of x-axis scale is silly, though. With a better scale you'll see it better.
5. your code says `th` (presumably for theta) where your text says alpha. Please be consistent.

If you edit appropriately, more could be said

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad explanation. You sure are knowledgeable in the subject, could you please clarify a bit point 3? That was what i was trying to ask, I'm not sure exactly how to do it differently. I thought of summing the values and then the result would be a Gamma. Would that be the correct way? 
 
Regarding the point 1, it was an attempt to match the scale with the prior distribution function so it would be easier to compare one another.

Comment: Don't guess at what to do to compute the likelihood function on a sample. What is the *definition* of likelihood?